# Not able to Run cd command with restricted user!

Tags: bash, cd-command, restricted-shell

I have restricted a normal user to limited commands using `rbash`, now am not able to `cd` (change directory) to other directory,can someone help me how can i run `cd` command with restricted user, please find the error which am getting when performimg cd command

```
-rbash: cd: restricted
```

Answer (score 4):

That's the whole point with `rbash`. You are not allowed to use `cd`!

From [the Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html):

> #### 6.10 The Restricted Shell
>
> If Bash is started with the name rbash, or the --restricted or -r
>   option is supplied at invocation, the shell becomes restricted. A
>   restricted shell is used to set up an environment more controlled than
>   the standard shell. A restricted shell behaves identically to bash
>   with the exception that the following are disallowed or not performed:
>
> - Changing directories with the `cd` builtin.
> - Setting or unsetting the values of the `SHELL`, `PATH`, `ENV`, or `BASH_ENV` variables.
> - Specifying command names containing slashes.
> - Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the `.` builtin command.
> - Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the `-p` option to the `hash` builtin command.
> - Importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup.
> - Parsing the value of `SHELLOPTS` from the shell environment at startup.
> - Redirecting output using the `>`, `>|`, `<>`, `>&`, `&>`, and `>>` redirection operators.
> - Using the `exec` builtin to replace the shell with another command.
> - Adding or deleting builtin commands with the `-f` and `-d` options to the `enable` builtin.
> - Using the `enable` builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins.
> - Specifying the `-p` option to the command builtin.
> - Turning off restricted mode with `set +r` or `set +o restricted`.

Comment: Thanks!! Is there any other way to restrict user other than rbash??

Comment: I suggest that you search online using the terms "linux jail user", and if you have more questions (after researching), then post a new one. Best regards.